# There in PDF not change the style which i have added in HTML?

Tags: php, html, pdf-generation, tcpdf

In my site, I am using the TCPDF to generate the pdf from HTML ,and i also using the image in header but i can't show the style which i added in html.

---

Ljubljana,'.date("d.m.Y").'

#### '.JText::_('BUYER_NAME').':

'.$my->name.'

#### '.JText::_('BOOKING_CODE').':

'.$ticketNo.'

This table in PDF not margin from top with its given 35px.
plz help.......

Answer (score 0):

If you refer to the original [documentation](http://www.tcpdf.org/docs.php) and [examples](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples.php) of TCPDF when checking for this question, you'll probably find yourself without any valid solution.

This is because TCPDF hasn't a full CSS complementation, but just for basic formatting. With `getHtmlDomArray()` you'll probably be able to access this CSS partial use, such as `font-family` and [others](http://www.tcpdf.org/examples/example_061.phps). So, if you want to use full CSS with TCPDF, you are using a wrong tool and I'd advise to try other one that would make the same output, as many as they are.

Anyway, be sure to check new versions of that implementation, in case you really want to keep using it, as they might add more implementations on the future.